# Defining size to a custom array type in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How to define size for any custom component based array like **ImageView**?

I've tried the following code with a type mismatch error,

```
    private var dots: Array<ImageView>? = null
    dots = arrayOfNulls<ImageView>(size)
```

Here's the actual Java code,

```
private ImageView[] dots;
dots = new ImageView[dotsCount];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify that the element type of the array is nullable:

```
private var dots: Array<ImageView?>? = null
```